# Visual Studio 2005 Installer is launched after reboot

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I recently reinstalled visual studio and my machine froze during setup. While the setup completed successfully when I ran the installer next time, the "configuring visual studio 2005" window started to pop up at every reboot. To me it seems like an entry in registry somewhere ( runonce?) but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link with a list all of the places in the registry that could cause something to run at startup:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137367

I would also check your Start->Programs->Startup directory to see if anything is there.

If all else fails, run MSCONFIG and take a look at the startup items there and see if you see it.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. It did help but I ended up using Windows installer cleaner utility.